# Fingerprint Reader in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, fingerprint

Has anyone had any success using a fingerprint scanner in an ASP.NET application? I am looking for a solution where a user would click a button in our web application that would then trigger a locally installed fingerprint reader, take the fingerprint and then upload the scanned image back to the server.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, there are four approaches to this:

1. An ActiveX control (many fingerprint reader makers provide one with their SDKs.)
2. A BHO and other plugins for other browsers
3. A server on the client that the web server can call to based on IP address.
4. A USB to Ethernet device that provides 3 but in a hardware form.

Each has pros and cons, that you need to analyze with the particulars of your application.

However, probably a better solution is simply to use the automation clients that come with fingerprint readers. Everyone I have seen provides some sort of mechanism to detect when a web page appears, scans a fingerprint, and automatically fills in a password. Is there a reason you can't use that with a random password?