# Calling windows application exe within web service method

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-services, wcf

I have 1 web application 1 web service and 1 windows application and I am calling a web service method from web application and in that method i am calling windows application exe. I have put windows application exe on server machine and also host that web service on server machine. If I the web service is hosted on local iis then its working and if it is on server IIS then it gives me Time Out error

Comment: Can you please explain better what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: i have called a web service method in web application. in that method i have executed exe. that exe work only when the web service is hosted on local IIS and giving me time out error when web service is hosted on server IIS

Answer (score 2):

Web service executes in the context of the ASP.NET worker process on the Web server. If you use the `Process.Start` method in an ASP.NET Web page or server control, the new process executes on the Web server with restricted permissions.

[Give permission](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317012) for ASP.NET worker process account to interact with desktop or allow ASP.NET worker process to run in SYSTEM account.

1. Open Control Panel and follow these steps: For Windows NT: click Services. For Windows 2000, Windows XP, and .NET Server: click Administrative Tools, and then click Services.
2. Double-click IIS Admin Service.
3. On the Log On tab, select the Allow Service to Interact with Desktop check box. Remember to run IIS Admin Service as a local system.
4. Stop and restart the IIS Admin Service.

Comment: Currently I am working on SecuGen fingerprint device but I have its windows based dll (SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows) only so i can not used that dll on web application. Please suggest me how to use secuGen device on web application.

Comment: Most likely, you cannot avoid using ActiveX, because, by apparent security reasons: a Web application does not have access to a client system, and the fingerprint reading is not a part of W3 standards

Comment: discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009346/fingerprint-reader-in-asp-net